# Filter PCAP files using scapy based on annotations in the packets

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

How can I filter the packets based on annotations in the packets using python?

In wireshark, I can filter just by `frame.comment`

I have tried the following but is unable to.

```
from scapy.all import *

for pkt in sniff(offline=self.pcap_file_name, filter="frame.comment"):
    print(pkt)
```

I get this output: `Could not open/read pcap file: tcpdump is not available`

But when I omit the `filter`, I am able to read all the packets

Comment: Did you... try to install tcpdump ?

Comment: You're right, lol. At first was doing it in windows which I did not installed tcpdump. After switching to linux, it works fine